# How can I reference elements with names like 'element-name' using SimpleXml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can I parse an XML document like this:

```
<feed>
  <item>
    <element-name>Element value</element-name>
  </item>
</feed>
```

If I try the following, it doesn't work:

```
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

foreach($xmlObject->item as $item) {
    $elementName= $item->element-name; // Obviously doesn't work.
}
```

I've tried:

```
$item->element_name;
$item->elementname;
$item->elementName;
```

None work.  How do I access this element's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$name = "element-name";
$item->{$name};
```

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_string` does not like it when you try and pass it element nodes with dashes/hyphens (`-`).

You have two options here.

Encapsulate the element name with curly braces (`{}`):

```
$elementName = $item->{'element-name'};
```

Or turn it into a variable you can replace out:

```
$elementNameNode = 'element-name';
$elementName = $item->$elementNameNode;
```